# Delete APN on LG-P500

Tags: settings, mms, lg-optimus-one, apn

The LG-P500 does not allow to delete/disable MMS APN. The problem is that if I define my own APN, the original one, which cannot be deleted, is still used by messaging application...

Anybody knows how I can put there my own APN instead of the operator defined one?

BR
STeN

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding the messaging settings to the APN you created? You can add both webs as mms settings and then select that APN.